# android row not updating in sqlite DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app where i am trying to update a row in the Transactions table in my DB. Here's the table.

```
//table transactions column names
    public static final String C_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // special for id internally in system
    public static final String C_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String C_COMPANY_ID = "companyid";
    public static final String C_PERSON_ID = "person";
    public static final String C_NAME = "name";
    public static final String C_TAG_ID = "tagid";
    public static final String C_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String C_TAG_SCAN_TIME = "tagscantime";
    public static final String C_TAG_SENTSERVER_TIME = "tagsentservertime";
    public static final String C_TRANSACTIONS_LATITUDE = "transactionslatitude";
    public static final String C_TRANSACTIONS_LONGITUDE = "transactionslongitude";
```

.

When i insert a row into this table the column C_TAG_SENTSERVER_TIME is set to null. This is because i haven't at this point posted the transaction to the webservice. Once i get the response back from the server, i would like to update the row in the phone's DB with 'sent to server time'. At the moment i try to get the last row in the DB, i then try to get that row's id, that is the passed to the method that updates the row. Currently the result of

```
String[] param = {c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_ID))};
```

is returnig null. Here's the rest of the update method. Why is the above call returning null?

```
public void updateTransactionWithServerTime(DateTime sentToServerAt) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c = null;

        c = db.query(DBHelper.TABLETRANSACTIONS, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToLast()) {
                String[] param = {c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_ID))};
                Log.e(TAG, "C_ID = " + param[0]);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                  values.put(C_TAG_SENTSERVER_TIME, sentToServerAt.getMillis());

                 int res =  db.update(DBHelper.TABLETRANSACTIONS, values, LoginValidate.C_ID+"=?", param[0]);

                  Log.e(TAG, "done the update on trans table num of rows affected is " + res);

            }

         }
        c.close();
        db.close();
    }//end of updateTransactionWithServerTime
```

[edit1]

```
private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        // database name and version number
        public static final String DB_NAME = "carefreemobiledb.db";
        public static final int DB_VERSION = 26;

        //table names
        public static final String TABLETRANSACTIONS = "transactions";
        public static final String TABLECARER = "carer";
        public static final String TABLETRANSACTIONSMAP = "transactionsmap";
        public static final String TABLEPHONE = "phone";

        // public static final String C_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // special for id
        // internally in
        // system


        public DBHelper() {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String sqlToCreateTransactionsTable = String
                    .format("create table %s ( %s INT primary key, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT," +
                            " %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s INT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT )",
                            TABLETRANSACTIONS, C_ID, C_TYPE, C_COMPANY_ID, C_PERSON_ID,
                            C_NAME, C_TAG_ID, C_STATUS, C_TAG_SCAN_TIME, C_TAG_SENTSERVER_TIME,
                            C_TRANSACTIONS_LATITUDE, C_TRANSACTIONS_LONGITUDE);

            db.execSQL(sqlToCreateTransactionsTable);
            Log.e(TAG, "oncreate " + sqlToCreateTransactionsTable);
```

Comment: you could always do raw queries. "update table set col='value' where id=#;"

Comment: @toadzky Hi i think this is the problem i have. String[] param = {c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_ID))}; it's returning null, so i can't get the id of the row

Comment: Please show how you create the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` to get an autoincrementing column; `INT` is not enough.

Comment: Hey thanks alot it works fine now. Can you tell me why it has to be Integer and not INT?

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] str new String[c.getCount()];
int i = 0;
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                str[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_ID));
                i++;
            }
```

Comment: i need to update the last row in the table, this is why i need the id from a particular column. Sorry if i'm missing what you've suggested

Comment: Hi no i'm afraid that doesn't work. Also do you know why String[] param = {c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_ID))};
is null

Comment: Parameters need a `?` in the query string.

Comment: @CL Hi i've updated the post and tested it but still doesn't work. I think the problem starts with the following being set to null, i need the id from the row. String[] param = {c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_ID))};

Comment: if that line is null does that mean that sqlite is not autoincrementing the id column?

Answer (score 0):

Your code that reads the ID from the cursor looks correct, assuming that the table actually contains that column.

Anyway, reading all fields of all rows of the table just to get one value is inefficient, and without an `ORDER BY`, there is no guarantee that the latest record is the last one.

I'd recommend this query to read the last ID:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT max(" + LoginValidate.C_ID + ")" +
                     " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLETRANSACTIONS, null);
```

However, you can plug this as subquery directly into the update query:

```
int res = db.update(DBHelper.TABLETRANSACTIONS, values,
                    LoginValidate.C_ID + " = " +
                     "(SELECT max("+LoginValidate.C_ID+")" +
                     " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLETRANSACTIONS + ")", null);
```

Comment: should the following line be of type String. I mean does the id column be a string or an int for sqlite to auto increment. Does sqlite even autoincrement? public static final String C_ID = BaseColumns._ID;

Comment: also c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_ID)) is returning null