# How to update row that is clicked

Tags: android, sql, database

with the code below I am able to update row with id corresponding to the number given in updateDiaryEntry, eg. row no 2:

```
private void saveItToDB(long rowId) {
    dba.open();
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(((TextView) editText).getText().toString(), 2);
    dba.close();
    ((TextView) editText).setText("");
}
```

Although, when I try to use rowId instead, nothing gets updated. I try to update row that is clicked, so there is more code here:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Position is the number of the item clicked
    //You can use your adapter to modify the item
    long rowId = adapter.getItemId(position); //Will return the clicked item
    saveItToDB(rowId);
}
```

Here is more code with the adapter:

```
public class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<MyDiary> fragment_monday;

    public DiaryAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        fragment_monday = new ArrayList<MyDiary>();
        getdata();

        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new EditListItemDialog(Monday.this, null, position).show();

                return true;       
            }
        });

    }

    public void getdata(){
        Cursor c = dba.getdiaries();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String title =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                String content =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));

                MyDiary temp = new MyDiary(title,content);
                fragment_monday.add(temp);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {return fragment_monday.size();}
    public MyDiary getItem(int i) {return fragment_monday.get(i);}
    public long getItemId(int i) {return i;}
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        View v = arg1;
        if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.diaryrow,  null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.mdiary = getItem(arg0);
        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.mdiary.title);


        v.setTag(holder);

        return v;


    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        MyDiary mdiary;
        TextView mTitle;


    }

}
```

and here is MyDB file:

```
public class MyDB {
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = null;
    private static final String KEY_ID = null;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context context;
    private final MyDBhelper dbhelper;



    // Initializes MyDBHelper instance
    public MyDB(Context c){

        context = c;
        dbhelper = new MyDBhelper(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null,
                                        Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);

    }


    // Closes the database connection
    public void close()
    {
        db.close();

    }

    // Initializes a SQLiteDatabase instance using MyDBhelper
    public void open() throws SQLiteException
    {

        try {
            db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.v("Open database exception caught", ex.getMessage());
            db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }

    }

    // updates a diary entry (existing row)
        public boolean updateDiaryEntry(String title, long rowId)
        {

            ContentValues newValue = new ContentValues();
            newValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME, title);

            return db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, newValue, Constants.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null)>0;

        }

    // Reads the diary entries from database, saves them in a Cursor class and returns it from the method
    public Cursor getdiaries()
    {
        Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        return c;
    }


}
```

I thought that the code already gets the row Id and I could use rowId instead of the number to update row that is clicked, but somehow no row is getting updated. Can anyone point me to my error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide args in a prepared statement style.

Taken from the BARACUS Android framework's BaseDao:

```
 db.update(rowMapper.getAffectedTable()
         , cv
         , getIdField() + "= ?"
         , new String[]{item.getId().toString()});
```

so in your terms:

```
db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME
        , newValue
        , Constants.KEY_ID + "= ?"
        , new String[]{ rowId.toString() })
```

Comment: at rowId.toString I get error Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type long

Comment: Double.valueOf(rowId).toString() should do the job

Comment: db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME
        , newValue
        , Constants.KEY_ID + "= ?"
        , new String[]{ Double.valueOf(rowId).toString() })

Comment: then it asks me to add return type false

Comment: but : maybe a Double[] instead of String[] does the job, too. I am not aware of the parameter type atm. The String[] solution works for my framework.

Comment: ah, you have a >0 at the end in order to return a boolean ;-)

Comment: strange, here is the source https://github.com/gorefest/baracus-framework/blob/master/src/main/java/net/mantucon/baracus/dao/BaseDao.java line 307. it works perfectly there.

Comment: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: your code should be :   return db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, newValue, Constants.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{rowId})>0;

Comment: but the rows are still not getting updated when in updateDiaryEntry I change number to rowId.

Comment: Have looked into the database afterwards? Ah, I just noticed this boolean localTransaction = handle == null; in line 285. It is always null, so I open a transaction and commit at the end. Maybe You should try that, too.

Comment: how can I implement it?

Comment: Ok, start with db.beginTransaction();. After that, Your transaction is running. Then You make Your update like I showed You. In the end, You simply call db.setTransactionSuccessful(); and db.endTransaction(); - that's it :) Oh and by the way, maybe You should select the records after that and dump them to the log in order to verify that the Update really has been done.

Comment: db.setTransactionSuccessful(); screams Unreachable code

Comment: well, this means that you placed the method call behind Your return statement....

Comment: have you checked it inside of the database? make a select and dump the value to the log. remember, normally a gui value is not modified automatically when the database value is changed.

Comment: I refreshed the view but the value is not changed.

Comment: Have You verified that You use the correct primary key type?See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955930/android-row-not-updating-in-sqlite-db

Comment: I don't understand why I cannot get the clicked row updated. I must be missing something, like querring wrong way for the row id.

Comment: how to use integer primary key?

Comment: CREATE TABLE Foo(INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, and so on and so on) ... when You create the table. Somewhere You have a create statement for the table, and the PK Column must be of type INTEGER.